# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for bean defined in JavaConfig

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired, xmlbeans

I was using XML configuration on my project earlier, and everything was working.

We're moving gradually to java config, so right now I'm at a stage where I'm using a mix of Java and XML configs.

Here's the problem, there is a bean defined in my XML config : beanA.

```
<bean id="beanA" class="BeanA" />
```

The class BeanA has an autowired dependency on BeanB.

```
class BeanA {
     @Autowired
     BeanB beanB;
}
```

Earlier, this beanB was also in XML config, and it ran correctly.

Now, I have made this change, and it is no longer working :

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public BeanB beanB() {
        return new BeanB();
    }
}
```

Apart from adding `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations, is there something else required to do that I am missing?

I'm getting the following error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'beanB': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanA';
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxxxx.yyy.zzzzzzzzzzzz.abc.beanA' available:
>
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please note,

1. I have only moved beanB to be created via java config.
2. BeanA actually has more dependencies, so I cannot move it to java config at this stage (will be doing proper migration later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring **does not** load the beans from the classes annotated with `@Configuration` unless it has been **told to** look for classes with this annotation.

To make spring look for these classes, the following must be added in your xml configuration :

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxx.yyy.zzzz">`

It will then recursively find and initialize all the beans in the package com.xxxxx.yyy.zzzz.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add configuration for BeanB as well in the xml configuration. as when  the program is run it loads all the bean definition from xml configuration file.  So it looks like BeanB definition is missing in configuraion file.

Comment: Well so here's the thing, I *did* have it working with beans in xml file, but I wanted to move them out. So, BeanB definition was deliberately removed from XML.